# Wordpress Widget "is_active_sidebar" always returns true

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a facebook-like-box widget in wordpress:

```
<div class="widget-content">
            <div class="fb-like-box" 
                data-href="<?php echo $fbpageurl; ?>" 
                data-width="260" 
                data-colorscheme="<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-1') ) { echo "light"; } else { echo "dark"; } ?>"
                data-show-faces="true" 
                data-header="false" 
                data-stream="false" 
                data-show-border="false"
            ></div>
        </div>
```

other file:

```
register_sidebar( array(
            // [...]
            'id' => 'sidebar-1',
            // [...]
    ) );
```

If I use the widget, it always return the "true" value... I don't know why. My other sidebar names are "sidebar-2", "sidebar-3"...

Comment: it's not really clear what you use `is_active_sidebar` for? Do you want to test if the widget is currently in 'sidebar-1' ?
if this is what you are looking for then there is no function to test that, you must use CSS or JS to change the look of your widget depending on what sidebar it's in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use  [is_dynamic_sidebar()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_dynamic_sidebar), because this Conditional Tag checks if the current sidebar has active widgets, not like [is_active_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar) that check only the sidebar is active or not (in use).

Answer (score 0):

is_active_sidebar returns true if any widget is active inside of sidebar even if sidebar isn't shown on that page.

I can see that your trying to change color but I can't seem to figure out how and why. Maybe some more info would help figuring the solution to your problem.

[is_active_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar)